# How can I fetch values from a same column into different textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am having difficulty in displaying the dynamic data into text-boxes. I am in a situation where I have multiple text-boxes and I want to fetch value from table where column name is 'registration_charges' and 'amount'. Now column registration_charges' contains data e.g., 'OPD_CHARGES', 'DR.Charges' and 'amount' column has data e.g.,:- 5000, 1000. I want to display amount in text box accordingly.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" >OPD Ch.</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtopd_charges" runat="server" Width="100px"  
style="text- 
align: right;float:right;margin-right:15px;">/-</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label runat="server" >DR Ch.</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdr_charges" runat="server" Width="100px"  
style="text- 
align: right;float:right;margin-right:15px;">/-</asp:TextBox>
```

Back-end code:

```
//connection code
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT amount FROM 
Mst_Charges WHERE registration_charges IN('OPD_CHARGES', 
DR.Charges')",  con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   txtopd_charges.Text = ???
   txtdr_charges.Text =  ???         

}
else
{

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Comment: Why the actual code doesn't work ? Have you tried the query in your query editor ?

Answer (score 1):

In your query you must select `registration_charges` along with the `amount`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT amount,registration_charges  FROM 
   Mst_Charges WHERE registration_charges IN('OPD_CHARGES', 
   DR.Charges')",  con);
```

You can fetch data of your DataTable like this:

```
txtopd_charges.Text = dt.Rows[0]["amount"].ToString();
txtdr_charges.Text =  dt.Rows[0]["registration_charges"].ToString();
```

**UPDATED**
You can bind the data with `Repeater` and initialized your textbox inside of the `ItemTemplate` which will repeat your data exist in DataTable.

**Aspx Code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtopd_charges" Text='<%# Eval("amount") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdr_charges" Text='<%# Eval("registration_charges") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in your **C#**

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
   Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i want output like this txtopd_charges.Text = 5000
txtdr_charges.Text=1000 i.e from single column i am trying to fetch multiple values

Comment: Do you wanna show the sum of that value, or want to show them independently? Show any sample data of your response from SQL Query, so that would help a lot to find out the solution.

Comment: You can add Repeater in your Webform and bind it with the DataTable, then you can access these data in your TextBox.